# Returning constructor-less object as output parameter

Tags: c++

I want to return an object from a function as an output parameter, but the object has no default constructor so I can't do this:

```
bool FindFlaggedObject(MyObject& myObject)
{
    std::vector<MyObject> myObjects = GetSomeObjectList();
    for (UINT i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        if (myObjects[i].Flag) {
            myObject = myObjects[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void main()
{
    MyObject myObject;  // NOT ALLOWED - OBJECT HAS NO DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    if (FindFlaggedObject(myObject))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, it looks like I should return it on the heap and manage it with a shared_ptr instance, like this:

```
bool FindFlaggedObject(MyObject& myObject)
{
    std::vector<MyObject> myObjects = GetSomeObjectList();
    for (UINT i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        if (myObjects[i].Flag) {
            myObject = new MyObject(myObjects[i]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void main()
{
    MyObject* myObjectPtr;
    if (FindFlaggedObject(myObjectPtr))
    {
        std::shared_ptr<MyObject> myObject(myObjectPtr);

        ...
    }
}
```

The downside is that anyone calling the method will have to remember that he is responsible for deallocating the object.
**What is the best practice for returning constructor-less objects as output parameters?**

Comment: Do you mean "non-copy-constructible objects" when you say "constructor-less objects"? If not, where do the objects come from?

Comment: @Andre: Sorry, the objects are constructed internally (e.g. by friend classes). They do actually have a copy constructor, but no parameter-less constructor, making it difficult to allocate on the stack before calling the method.

Answer (score 5):

Return by value is almost always the best solution if the object
supports copy (and objects which will be declared on the stack should
generally support copy).  If the function can fail, and not always 
return an object, you can use some sort of `Fallible` or `Maybe` class:

```
Fallible<MyObject>
FindFlaggedObject()
{
    std::vector<MyObject> objects = GetSomeObjectList();
    std::vector<MyObject>::const_iterator current = objects.begin();
    while ( current != objects.end() && !current->flag ) {
        ++ current;
    }
    return current == objects.end()
        ? Fallible<MyObject>()
        : Fallible<MyObject>( *current );
}
```

You might reflect, though: if GetSomeObjectList() can always return a
reference to an existing list (rather than constructing a list
internally), and you modify it to return a const reference, you could
just return a pointer:

```
MyObject const*
FindFlaggedObject()
{
    std::vector<MyObject> const& objects = GetSomeObjectList();
    std::vector<MyObject>::const_iterator current = objects.begin();
    while ( current != objects.end() && !current->flag ) {
        ++ current;
    }
    return current == objects.end()
        ? NULL
        : &*current;
}
```

This is a very typical C++ idiom.

Comment: I'd like add that this idiom might result in dangling pointers if `GetSomeObjectList` is _not_ referentially transparent. So, I would advise to use a shared_ptr instead (like others proposed).

Comment: @James: What if the object has to be or ought to be returned in an output parameter?

Comment: @Andre `shared_ptr` is about the worst solution imaginable.  It requires dynamic allocation, and imposes the use of a `shared_ptr` in the client code---and `shared_ptr` is only rarely appropriate.  If the object isn't referentially transparent (his name `GetSomeObjectList` suggests, however, that it should be), then `Fallible<MyObject>` is really the only valid solution.

Comment: @drifter C++ does __not__ support out parameters other than a return value: you can choose between in (by value or by const reference), or inout (by non-const reference or pointer), but in both cases, the client code must be able to construct an instance.  (This is an argument in favor of always providing a default constructor.  If there is no way to default construct a usable object, however, the arguments against providing one are even stronger.  The whole point of C++ constructors is that there should never be an unusable object.)

Comment: @James: That makes sense, thanks. But one final note, you shouldn't provide parameter-less constructors just so you can pass empty inoperable objects around, right?

Comment: @drifter If you need to pass empty inoperable objects around, then you'll need a default constructor to create them.  Whether allowing inoperable objects to exist in the first place is another question; usually (but there are exceptions), it is preferable for the constructor to raise an exception rather than leave an object in an inoperable state.

Comment: @JamesKanze Of course, using `shared_ptr` imposes the use of `shared_ptr` (I see no problem with that -- apart from being a tautology). Could you give a reason why using `shared_ptr` is only rarely appropriate, as opposed to having the risk of dangling pointers?
Could you give an explanation about `Fallible`? I never heard about that.

Comment: @Andre It's not a tautology: if you use, say `std::auto_ptr`, then the client code can switch to `shared_ptr` if that is more appropriate, or a raw pointer, or a home made pointer, or anything else he wants.  If you use `shared_ptr`, you've locked the client into that strategy, because once an object is owned by a `shared_ptr`, there's no way of getting it back.  In this case, there's no reason to use dynamic allocation to begin with, but if there were, the appropriate return type would be `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @Andre With regards to `Fallible`, see Barton and Nackman.  (Despite its age, it's still one of the best books around.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning a `bool` and passing in a reference have the function return a smart pointer, ensuring the caller cannot forget to deallocate:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> myObjectPtr = FindFlaggedObject();
if (myObjectPtr)
{
    // Found flagged object.
}

std::shared_ptr<MyObject> FindFlaggedObject()
{
    MyObject* result = nullptr;
    std::vector<MyObject> myObjects = GetSomeObjectList();
    for (UINT i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        if (myObjects[i].Flag) {
            result = new MyObject(myObjects[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return std::shared_ptr<MyObject>(result);
}
```

Comment: This requires dynamic allocation of an object, and it might be an expensive operation.

Comment: Thanks. Would you use this approach if it were a library function?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @drifter?

Comment: @hmjd: Would you use shared_ptr in the function prototype if you were writing it for a library.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an out parameter, return a value.  Since the value is optional, as indicated by the current return type of bool, you can use `boost::optional` for that purpose:

```
boost::optional<MyObject> FindFlaggedObject()
{
    std::vector<MyObject> myObjects = GetSomeObjectList();
    for (UINT i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        if (myObjects[i].Flag) {
            return myObjects[i];
        }
    }
    return boost::none;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `boost::optional` which describes best what's intended here.

Answer (score 0):

No need to construct an automatic object with an default constructor.
Just pass constructor parameters.

```
void main()
{
   MyObject myObject (12); 
   if (FindFlaggedObject(myObject))
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

On the other side, why don't do it this way?

```
MyObject FindFlaggedObject()
{
 std::vector<MyObject> myObjects = GetSomeObjectList();
 for (UINT i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); i++)
 {
     if (myObjects[i].Flag) {
         return myObjects[i];
     }
 }
 return 0;
}

void main()
{
   MyObject* res = FindFlaggedObject();
   if (res != 0) {
      ...
   }
}
```

You don't have to care to delete **res** as long **res** is still member in GetSomeObjectList